# How to hide all CollectionViewCell when user slides and tap fingers on them (uses touch gestures)?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, swift4

I'm developing screen test app in iOS, I want to hide all the CollectionViewCell when user sliding & tap finger on them.
I have used touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded methods but didn't worked. open for other logics as well.

Below is the screenshot of the CollectionView.

[image: This]

Comment: " sliding & tap finger " at the same time?

Comment: Yes for tap did select is there, I want both together

Comment: "user sliding " - What kind of? Horizontal Vertical? Tinder Type?

Comment: All direction Up, Down ,Left, Right

Comment: To handle such situation, you need to create UITapGesture on UICollectionView,While tapping on scrolling controllers (UITableView, UICollection) does not call touchesBegan method.because they have their own selector method.

Here is the link that guides you , how to create Tap Gesture on UICollectionView, with help of this u will get another gesture idea as well.

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/collection-view-default-gestures/

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, not every cell hide on which finger is sliding.

Answer (score 0):

```
func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let point: CGPoint = gesture.location(in: collectionBlocks)
        if let theIndexPath: IndexPath = collectionBlocks.indexPathForItem(at: point)
        {
            let selectedCell = collectionBlocks.cellForItem(at: theIndexPath)
            selectedCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```